# I need help writing a mysql query that combines 3 data tables codeiniger 4

Tags: sql, mysql, codeigniter-4

I have 3 mysql database tables including:

**article ( id | name )**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | article 1 |
| 2 | article 2 |
| 3 | article 3 |

**category ( id | name )**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | category 1 |
| 2 | category 2 |
| 3 | category 3 |

**article_category ( id | article_id | category_id )**

One article can combine many categories

| id | article_id | category_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 3 |

My task is to retrieve a list of records (no duplicates) in the article table with the name field (denoted categoryName) and id field (denoted categoryId) of the category table grouped together separated by commas. " , " (same as group_concat() statement)
The desired result will look like this:

| id | name | categoryName | categoryId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | article 1 | category 1,category 2 | 1,2 |
| 2 | article 2 | category 1,category 3 | 1,3 |
| 3 | article 3 |  |  |

help me write this mysql query.
Thank you!

Comment: Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. Ask about specific problems with your existing implementation.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: I was working with this query and it didn't work:
SELECT a.name, CONCAT(c.name,",") as categoryName , CONCAT(c.id,",") as categoryId 
FROM article a 
LEFT JOIN article_category ac ON a.id = ac.article_id
LEFT JOIN category c ON c.id = ac.category_id 
GROUP BY a.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

- `LEFT JOIN` (as you want all the articles irrespective of they are mapped to category or not) and
- `GROUP BY`(as you need one record per article) with
- `GROUP_CONCAT`(as you need comma-separated list of category id and name)

Use the following query:

```
select a.id, a.name,
       group_concat(c.name) as category_name,
       group_concat(c.id) as category_id
  from article a
 left join article_category ac on ac.article_id = a.id
 left join category c on ac.category_id = c.id
group by a.id, a.name
order by a.id
```

Comment: I want to ask why do we have to GROUP BY a.name when we already have GROUP BY a.id?

Comment: You do not need to include `a.name` in the `GROUP BY` clause, as it is functionally dependent on `a.id` (assuming `a.id` is a unique key).

Comment: What exactly are you answering? The OP showed no work at all. Please don't do someone's school assignment for them.